# Front-end registration validation

Tags: registration, validation

I have a front-end registration page and need to change the validation to add (minimum characters for information on the page and to make fields to accept only letters and other to accept only number how can I accomplish this )
if there is any guide or step by step it will be nice ,
thanks in advance 
my site is on this link : todo.net
registration page is : todo.net/register

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Regex (Regular Expression), `/^[a-zA-Z]{3,}$/` would for instance allow a minimum of 3 characters behind the comma would be the max value.

As for numbers it would be something like this `/^[0-9]{3,}$/`

http://regexr.com/ to test your regex en examples

And I would do this before the user is saved with the `users.onBeforeSaveUser` Event in a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The [MN Match Input](https://github.com/marionnewlevant/craft-mn_matchinput) plugin is a fieldtype for fields that match a regular expression. It sound to me as if it will do what you want.